# How to Import Keepass to Firefox LockWise

Tags: firefox, csv, keepass, keepassx

How to Import Keepass to Firefox LockWise? I meant transfer passwords from Keepass to Firefox LockWise.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Import Keepass to Firefox LockWise?

**There is no data import option in Lockwise.  So it is not possible to export your Keepass database directly into Lockwise.**

There are tools that are specific to Keepass that make the task of importing passwords into browsers stored in a Keepass database easier.  One possible work around is the fact, if you can import the passwords into Chrome, you can then import the passwords into Firefox using the "import Data from Another Browser" tool.  While the below quote is not specific to Lockwise it's still sort of applicable, since Lockewise also, does not have an import feature.  [The issue and potential workaround was at least linked to a discussion about Lockwise a few months ago.](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/bwqq1v/is_there_a_way_to_import_bitwarden/)

> Firefox doesn't have a CSV import ability, I decided to import the CSV
>   into Chrome, then run Firefox's "Import Data from Another Browser"
>   tool. When I run the "Import data from another browser" tool on
>   Firefox, it only imports some of the passwords from Chrome. If I
>   delete those passwords in Firefox and import again, the same exact
>   passwords are imported.

Source: [Chrome passwords with a NULL `action_uri` aren't imported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1543258)

> Importing of saved logins from another browser is available in the
>   upcoming release of Lockwise Desktop, the login manager native to
>   Firefox (as opposed to this web extension)
>
> You can access this functionality now via Firefox Nightly or Beta, and
>   on our release candidate for 70 via "Logins & Passwords"

As of October 28th 2019 the issue is still open and unassigned.

[Backup (Export & Import) option](https://github.com/mozilla-lockwise/lockwise-addon/issues/332)

However, as I hinted, there is a workaround the uses Chrome that exists.

[ffpass - Import and Export passwords for Firefox Quantum](https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass)

However, in order to get the password into Lockwise, you will have to disconnect the Firefox account more than likely.

Comment: It’s also disabled by default m, when it’s stable, I might update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Import into Firefox Lockwise has been available since Firefox 80,
but has had performance issues when importing many 100s of logins.
For more, see: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-login-data-file

Export the desired passwords from Keepass(x)(c) into a .csv file.

To import passwords into Firefox Lockwise,
go into about:config and set this pref to true:

```
signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled
```

Then go into Firefox Preferences or Options,
Privacy & Security, Logins and Passwords, Saved Logins;
and in the 3-dot ("...") menu in the upper right of the screen
click on "Import from a File" and select a .csv file to import.